# Editing a closed case

Tags: case

I have to provide permission to certain users to edit a closed case
how can i achieve this?

I tried to implement permission set,yet it is not working.

Comment: Hi Azeem, What permissions have you provided to users on case object ? And what permissions are provided on permission set ?

Comment: i have provided CRED view all and modify all permission in permission set

Comment: And what is the error you are getting when editing a closed case ? Can you provide any screenshot of the same ?

Comment: "Error:You cannot edit a closed case. Please contact your manager or system administrator"-    This error is thrown when i try to edit and save a closed case

Comment: Have you checked for validation rules on the Case object?

Comment: yeah... I have a validation rule restricting this. how can i overcom this ?

Comment: You need to modify your validation rule then so that the users who need permission to edit are not getting restricted in validation rule. Are there many users who need access to modify closed case or only 1-2 users ?

Comment: only 4 users need the permission. should i go by adding the four names to the validation ule

Comment: yes . You can do that then. Have a condition in your validation rule checking that if users other than these 4 are editing the closed case then only fire the rule. If these 4 are editing then do not fire the validation rule.

Comment: I am glad this helped you. Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you create a public group instead of hard coding those users into your validation rule. That way when you want to add or remove users from the list of people you who can edit closed cases, all you need to do is add or remove them from that group. Include membership in the public group you've created in your validation rule instead of those particular 4 users. That way you'll have a maintenance free solution. You won't ever need to edit the validation rule and your eventual replacement won't be scratching their head at some point in the future.